# What is global.isProd?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I've just started learning gulp, and I've been seeing a lot of people using global.isProd

Example of a gulp file:

```
'use strict';

global.isProd = false;

require('./gulp');
```

I just want to understand what is global and what is global.isProd or if you can tell me where I can find this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`global` is how you access true global variables in node.js.

So, `global.isProd = false;` is assigning a globally reachable property named `isProd` an initial value.

In node.js, the top level scope in a module (e.g. a `var xxx` declared at the top level of a module) is not actually the global scope.  This is different than Javascript in the browser.  The top level in a module is local to the module as a module is actually declared within a function scope that node.js sets up for each module.

So, to actually reach the global scope in node.js, it defines the symbol `global` that works somewhat like the `window` symbol in a browser.  If you want a globally accessible variable in node.js, you make it a property of the `global` symbol.

Here's what the [node.js doc](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) has to say about `global`.

---

The usual practice in nodejs is to avoid globals when practical because it prevents global naming conflicts and letting modules store their own state generally makes code more modular and more reusable.  Since module references are cached, you can usually get access to a common resource by simply referencing a property of a module or by calling a method in that module and just let the module itself take care of storing the common resource in its own module variables without using globals.  So, the cached module handles tend to make it simpler to get access to singleton resources via a given module.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. And yes it's just to see if I'm in production, so the production task sets it true.

Answer (score 0):

[`global`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) is just a variable in the module's scope. It's similar to `window` in the browser, except `global`'s scope covers the module only.

`isProd` is simply a "global variable" (again, only in the module) that tells your gulp file "Hey! This is NOT production." It's nothing special by the way, probably just used in your script.